# Android App for audio buttons

Tags: android, media

When I test my app everything is working but if I leave the app in the background for a bit and reopen or if the screen is off for a few moments it will force stop my app and I have to restart it to get it to work right again. Why is this happening? The app is just a few buttons that play audio.

E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set

Thats the only red error thing I get.

Answer (score 0):

It could be really anything. As long as you won't provide some source code examples and error logs nobody will be able to help you with your problem.